# Unable to group duplicated objects?

Tags: faces

[In this article](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html):

the last line says :

> To turn all duplicates into real objects, simply
>   select the icosphere and Object ‣ Apply ‣ Make Duplicates Real,
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. To make the icosphere and the tentacle a single object,
>   make sure they are all selected and go to Object ‣ Join, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

After doing this, I now have a large amount of objects. Great! but unfortunately, when I select all of them and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to combine the objects, nothing happens. Is there something preventing me from doing this or am I overlooking something?

Comment: i think ur selecting lamp and camera also so its not working

Comment: I specifically de-select all objects besides the newly created (read: added) objects. also I don't use lamps.

Comment: if all joining objects are meshes, they should join, afaik. could you post the model as it is now to check? you could use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Check that the active object is a mesh..

Answer (score 1):

Add a Monkey (Shift+A)

Add a Circle (Shift+A) set the vertices say 10 or 12 (left hand panel or press f6)

Select the monkey and then the circle (order is important here)
Press ctrl+P -- object

Go to the object panel right hand in duplication section select verts

press ctrl+Shift+A then

press ctrl+J

[image]